# cordova app fails in runtime on device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I've got a cordova app (build on Ionic framework) that fails in runtime on my Android device. Though It works fine on my genymotion emulator. The installation is working and the app starts, but it exits abruptly on some point.

I don't think I can debug it because the OS is Jelly Bean 4.2 (at least 4.4 needed). But can I find some logs? Maybe create them myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrate a robust crash analytics engine such as [ACRA](http://www.acra.ch/) or [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/), now bought by Twitter and made free as part of Fabric.

This way the engine records and sends crash data to your online account, including many many details and the stack trace.